# Style for tag is used instead of class style

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an app with `ASP.NET Web Forms` and
I want to use `bootstrap.css` for style.
The problem is, that for a button some properties
are used from the default Style.css which are defined for
tags, while the bootstrap ones are defined for classes like 'btn btn-primary'.
  This is the HTML markup

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" type="button"  CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server"` `Text="View data" OnClick="Button1_Click" />`

For the default Style.css

`input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button {

background-color: #d3dce0;

border: 1px solid #787878;

cursor: pointer;

font-size: 1.2em;

font-weight: 600;

padding: 7px;

margin-right: 8px;

width: auto;

}`

And bootstrap

`.btn-primary {

  color: #ffffff;

  background-color: #428bca;

  border-color: #357ebd;

}`

The primary thing I notice is that the background-color used is not from bootstrap
but form Style.css.

Why would this happen ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Perhaps some html markup could clarify? What exactly is happening, why didn't you expect it, and what *do* you expect?

Comment: If you want to use bootstarp, you should strip out `input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button` in your stylesheet. Then change your custom style a little bit at a time based on what you need; otherwise, it'll be really hard to debug.

Comment: @Win That is an option. But I am interested why is the tag taking precedence over the class.

Comment: Look like you have answered your own question - ***Why would this happen ?*** *The primary thing I notice is that the background-color used is not from bootstrap but form Style.css.*

Answer (score 0):

This is due to specificty. [The rules are](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity):

> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

This means:

```
input[type="button"]   has specificty   0,0,1,1
.btn-primary           has specificty   0,0,1,0
```

The first one's greater, so it'll be applied over the second one, regardless of order.

Comment: Is `type="button"` referring to a class here ? Also I tried to put a selector on ID to the button and the same thing happens